# Django field with list of objects

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to write a model *Question* which has a field called *universities* that is supposed to contain many universities, but I dont want to create oneToMany relationship as I just need the reference to *University* model in Question. I found ModelMultipleChoiceField which is ideal, but it applies only to forms and I can't seem to find anything similar for models.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield).

In your `Question` model, you would use it like this:

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    universities = models.ManyToManyField(
        "example.University",  # Replace 'example' with the app name
    )
```